# Per American pronunciation, "a ear" or "an ear"?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, spoken-english, indefinite-article, listening

I just watched [YEAR vs. EAR - American English Pronunciation (EAR vs. HEAR)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3R8VZSEla4&t=7s), and I hear absolutely no difference between the pronunciations of "ear" and "year", given we should use "a" for "year", can we use "a" for "ear"?

Update: demystified [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/294183/85627).

Comment: If you pronounce *year* and *ear* the same (native English speakers can tell the difference), shouldn't you want to distinguish between them by saying *an ear* and *a year*?

Comment: No. You never use "a" for "ear", and as someone who has learned some words in some other languages, training your ear is part of it. There is a difference between these words. You just have to listen for it.

Comment: Native British English speaker: I hear a perfectly clear difference in the video you linked to (and there is very little difference between the American and British pronunciation of the two words.) As the answers say, the problem is that you have not learned to hear the difference, not that there is no difference.

Comment: There are some British English dialects which *never* use "an" before any word. For example they would even say "a apple," not "an apple". But that is NOT standard English grammar or pronunciation.

Comment: Can you hear the difference in “or” and “your”?

Comment: I think finding some other videos might help train your ear as well — sometimes different voices will make something easier to hear. It still should always be "a year" and "an ear" though. @alephzero, there certainly is a difference for me (also British,). The only time "years" rhymes with "fears" for me is in O Little Town of Bethlehem!

Comment: If anything, I find the pronunciation of "a year" closer to "year" than "a ear".

Comment: I agree with @BeginTheBeguine  I don't want to say her pronunciation is bad, but I can normally very much tell the difference but can barely tell the difference in that video

Comment: *A Year* and the incorrectly said *A Ear* ARE pronounced exactly the same.  The *AY* sound of the word **A** blends into the *Y* sound of the word **Year**.  You hear *ayear* in both cases.  They only sound the same, however, when one incorrectly uses *A* in place on *An*.  The correctly said *An Ear* and the incorrectly said *An Year* do not sound the same.

Comment: @Jim, the y sound is much clearer in _your_ than in _year_, because the following vowel contrasts with it so strongly. For example, compare _Eeyore_ to _eeyear_.

Comment: @TonyK - Exactly!!  So now that you know what to listen for you can better detect it in “year”

Comment: @Kevin I'm also a native BrE speaker and perfectly willing to say her pronunciation is bad, considering the intent is to help people tell the difference!

Comment: @OJFord I'm a native AmE speaker.  My reaction to the question (before watching the video) was a credulous "how can you not hear the difference between ear and year". Then I watched the video..

Comment: @EllieK what English accent do you have? I am a native speaker of English, English parents, Canadian, many years in the US, and I have trouble imagining “a ear” sounding the same as “a year”. No blend when I say it. Tongue differences in the first sound of “ear” and “year”.

Comment: @KrazyGlew - I am not sure about tongue differences between *ear* and *year*.  I would assume the difference is between the pronunciation of the word **a**.   I say Ay - long A which contains a *ye* with a long E at the end.   My *Ay* already contains the first sound of *Year*.  In that case they merge into one sound.  The *Ay* expresses the same sound, one time, when ear is appended.  I can enunciate a difference between to two but in casual speaking they would sound the same.

Comment: @EllieK: I also say long A, originally I was going to suggest that you were using short A. However when I say “a ear” I make a burst sound, which I believe is called a plosive, at the beginning of “ear“,  sound which I do not have when I say a year. “A year“ blends, but “a year”  might be  blended. BTW we are probably going to get in trouble for having a discussion in comments. Although it is relevant to the original posters question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OP here, I got a perfect answer from a friend of mine who masters multiple languages, including Mandarin and English.

Here's my translated version of the explanation which he originally said in Mandarin:

> The reason why you can't hear the difference between "year" and "ear" is that in Mandarin, we don't distinguish the meaning of a character if it's pronounced tightly or relaxed, for example, the Chinese character「爱」(means "love" and is pronounced "ài"), we don't distinguish the meaning of it because it's pronounced tightly or relaxed, the meaning is always "love", but in some languages like Thai, the meanings do differ.
>
> So, for "ear", it's pronounced more tightly, like tightening your throat, whereas "year" is more relaxed.

Now I can tell the pronunciation difference between "year" and "ear".

---

Update: the pronunciation difference is "short i" vs "long e", since Mandarin doesn't have the "short i" sound, so it can be tricky for native Mandarin speakers to pronounce it correctly. For more information in this regard, you can refer to [this video clip](https://youtu.be/oMZpNB-gfAI?t=52) (in Mandarin).

Comment: The difference between "ear" and "year" is just the same as the difference between "or" & "your"; "earn" & "yearn"; "east" & "yeast"; "ess" (S) & "yes". One has a "yuh" pronounced at the start. I don't know what "relaxed" vs "tight" means here.

Comment: @Boann: _your_ contrasts with _or_ much more strongly than _year_ contrasts with _ear_, because the following vowel changes the tongue position significantly. The same is true to a lesser extent for _yearn_ and _earn_. (But I don't know what "relaxed" vs "tight" means either, at least in the context of "ài".)

Answer (score 15):

Most native speakers can hear the distinction.  Like Peter Shor said, saying "an ear" and "a year" can help the listener understand which one you mean.  Words beginning with vowel sounds always use "an", but words starting with consonants ("y" is a consonant here) use "a".

[Some examples of "ear"](https://forvo.com/word/ear/#en) and ["year"](https://forvo.com/word/year/#en).  All I can say is that "year" begins with a harder, tighter "y" sound, while "ear" has a relaxed, smooth "e" sound.

Comment: I would say that _all_ native speakers with normal hearing can hear the distinction.

Comment: Yes, even if they speak a local dialect that pronounces them the same way, they should still be able to hear the difference.

Answer (score 15):

The huge majority of Americans do both make and hear a difference in the sound of the words "ear" and "year." That fact that you do not hear that difference merely means that one of the sounds does not exist in your native language. My daughter-in-law's native language is Cantonese. I cannot distinguish all six tones; my ear was not trained from a young age to register differences in tone.

I assure you that if you say

> The girl is six ears old

Americans will understand you, but they will also immediately identify you as a non-native speaker.

Comment: Or it might be a particular local dialect that pronounces them alike.

Comment: @jamesqf Which dialect would that be? I know of none.

Comment: Native TexE speaker and trained vocalist here, and I think your _specific_ example is likely to actually be undetected: The tongue moves _through_ "y" on its way from "s" to "e", and so unless the speaker fully stops between "six" and "ears", the phantom "y" will actually be produced.

Comment: @jamesqf There may well be a dialect of American English that treats “ear” and “year” as homophones. I did not say that all Americans distinguished between them precisely because there may be rare dialects that do not. What are they, and approximately what percentage of Americans speak them?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- If the “y” phoneme is actually produced, then what is said is not “ears.” By the way, I have no trouble saying “six years” differently from “six ears.” I suspect you have missed my point. A native speaker of American English may indeed have difficulty saying my example sentence because it makes no sense. But only in Texas will anyone be unable to say “six ears” in a way distinguishable from “six years.”

Comment: @JeffMorrow "Rare" dialects? Perhaps in certain regions of the US, but I can think of quite a number of regional accents across the English speaking world where your example sentence wouldn't sound odd enough to immediately identify someone as a non-native speaker. I think because it sounds odd to you, you're making it sound a lot more obscure than it actually is. :/

Comment: @rsjaffe: I know of none (but I'm certainly no expert).  I just offer it as a possibility.  Either the listener is mishearing the sounds, or the speaker is not pronouncing them as most Americans would.

Comment: @DoctorPenguin The question is about American pronunciation. I made no assertion whatsoever about pronunciation outside the U.S.

Comment: The thing is that natural language is hugely redundant -- you could well say "the girl is six lkljkjj old" and most people will guess correctly what you wanted to say. We can follow conversations in surprisingly noisy environments, especially if we have context and visual clues that add to the redundancy (e.g. we can see the girl or vaguely know her and know it's not months).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Oh, I entirely agree. That is specifically why I said it would be understood. My point was that the use of the non-standard phoneme would be noticed (in a non-noisy environment). This comment pertains only to English as spoken in the U.S.

Comment: @chrysalis indeed - it's hard to drop it without a glottal stop, or poor reception :)

Answer (score 3):

**Part of the problem is that Americans don't universally pronounce the "Y" consonant with the same stress**

Let me be completely honest, Rachel in her video is pronouncing the "Y" in "year" ***so short*** that even I, born and raised in the U.S., had to wind the video back and listen a second time to readily hear the difference. I've never heard anyone pronounce the consonant that short. It's so short that I expect that if I heard her pronounce the words "yes" and the vocalization for the letter "S" ("es"), I'd have trouble hearing the difference.

However, I readily admit that I might be an oddity in the U.S. (even though I believe I hear people stress the "Y" much more than Rachel does in her video). For example, I fully pronounce the "wh" sound in "wheat," where (apparently) so many people de-stress the "h" to pronounce the word "weet" that [it was made fun of in the animated series *Family Guy*](https://youtu.be/u0DXHAruCB4).

Finally, for full disclosure, the faster a person speaks, the shorter (unemphasized or de-stressed) the stresses become. Therefore, your experience with this problem is *excellent,* because as you meet people who speak at different speeds, you'll recognize how the consonants become both over-stressed and under-stressed. If you're having trouble hearing the consonant "Y", listen to [Kristen from Tipsy Yak](https://youtu.be/ElJYEQxUb1M?t=100) pronounce the very Texan word, "y'all." Listen to that "Y." Now pronounce the word "y'ear." Yup, that's closer to how it should sound. Well, at least it's closer to what I think it should sound like.

**But, to answer your actual question** ([Source](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/using_articles.html))

> Remember, using **a** or **an** depends on the sound that begins the next word. So...
>
> - **a** + singular noun beginning with a consonant: **a** boy; **a** car; **a** bike; **a** zoo; **a** dog
> - **an** + singular noun beginning with a vowel: **an** elephant; **an** egg; **an** apple; **an** idiot; **an** orphan
> - **a** + singular noun beginning with a consonant sound: **a** user (sounds like 'yoo-zer,' i.e. begins with a consonant 'y' sound, so 'a' is used); **a** university; **a** unicycle
> - **an** + nouns starting with silent "h": **an** hour
> - **a** + nouns starting with a pronounced "h": **a** horse
>   In some cases where "h" is pronounced, such as "historical," you can use **an.** However, a is more commonly used and preferred.
>
>   A historical event is worth recording.

Comment: I'm sorry, 'Formally, "an" should be used whenever a word starts with a 'vowel [-letter?'] or an "h" ' is not accurate. An holly tree? An high hill? An unicorn? And the jury is out on hotel, historian.

Comment: "An hundred dollar bill" has _never_ been acceptable, because the first syllable in "hundred" is stressed.

Comment: @JBH Is pronouncing the *wh* a Chicago thing?

Comment: @EllieK The "ch" in Chicago is an "sh" sound ("sheet" -> "shicago"), but I have heard it pronounced occasionally as an "s" (sicago) and as a hard "ch" as in the word "chore." The human capacity to understand language is amazing because it can be so widely and wildly pronounced and yet we understand it.

Comment: 'An' is used whenever the following word starts with a vowel sound.  If you are one of the rare English speakers who pronounces 'historical' with a silent 'h' (like 'istorical') you should say 'an' everyone else should use 'a'.  Sometimes you find "an historical" in writing because, as I understand it, this was a more common pronunciation in the past.

Comment: Your "rules" are WAY too complicated. We use "a" before consonant sounds and "an" before vowel sounds. That's all there is to it. Furthermore, your rules aren't inclusive enough. Nouns have _nothing_ to do with it. For example, in the phrase "an hourly worker", "hourly" is not a noun. **Just keep it simple: "a" before consonant sounds, "an" before vowel sounds.**

Comment: @EllieK My well-to-do grand-aunt (whom my typo just called well-to-dog) certainly pronounced the 'h' in all 'wh' words. Until that episode of Family Guy I had no idea that pronunciation existed in the US. But then Stewie always has sounded English to me.

Comment: @user91988 If you look at the question's edit history, you'll see that I had a simpler set of rules. Then I was hand-slapped by Ed for not being accurate enough. The rules I've posted come [Purdue University's Online Writing Lab](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/using_articles.html). If you feel they're in error, you'll need to cite better authority than your own anonymous opinion.

Comment: @JBH Well, I gave a few examples of why they're incomplete. They're not "in error", they're just not inclusive enough. There's no need to appeal to authority. I gave examples.

Comment: @user91988 I appreciate your argument, but you're forgetting I cited rules from a writing lab. Their first sentence is entirely correct, "using a or an depends on the sound that begins the next word." They then cite, just as you did, a series of examples. They just did a better job than you did and understand their audience better.

Answer (score 1):

To amplify @[ludant's](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/294136/106592) last point:

Here's an illustration of the speech organs from *Vowels and Consonants* by Peter Ladefoged:

> [image: Vocal organs]

The sound at the beginning of *year* is called palatal approximant (/j/); the place where it is articulated/produced is the hard palate (as shown in the diagram). Unlike plosives (like *p, t, k* etc) there isn't any kind of closure of the vocal tract. It involves narrowing of the vocal tract at the hard palate but not narrow enough to produce turbulence, so it can be perceived as ‘harder’ or ‘tighter’.

By contrast, the sound at the beginning of *ear* is a vowel (/i ~ ɪ/) which means there is no narrowing of the vocal tract. The tongue while producing the vowel in *ear* is close to the palate but there is no constriction or narrowing of the vocal tract (because if there were narrowing, it would be classified as a consonant). It's produced with an open vocal tract therefore it sounds ‘softer’.

Anothe difference between /j/ and the vowel /i/ is that the vowel can form the peak of the syllable but /j/ can't.

According to [this article](https://home.cc.umanitoba.ca/%7Ekrussll/phonetics/articulation/describing-vowels.html) (University of Manitoba):

> I'm  fact, there is very little real difference between [i] and [j]. Both can be made with the tongue in the same position. [i] acts as the central part of a syllable, and typically lasts somewhat longer than a [j]. [j] does not act as the central part of a syllable and is typically fairly short. Essentially, [j] is simply an [i] that is acting as a consonant instead of a vowel.

Answer (score -13):

The word "year" begins with the consonant "y", which is also found in these words:

**y**ard

**y**es

**y**ield

**y**ours

**y**ule

... as well as in:

ba**y**

bo**y**

bu**y**

pra**y**

Ma**y**

... as well as in:

ma**y**or

pla**y**er

emplo**y**ing

enjo**y**ing

Whereas the word *ear* begins with a vowel.

Comment: In linguistics, vowels are sounds rather than letters.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: A minor inconvenience.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: But when we type on the computer (especially if we just use ASCII), we must use the letter y to represent the vowel and consonant sound(s).

Comment: These words in your answer don't include the ["y" consonant sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_palatal_approximant): bay, boy, buy, pray, may, employing, enjoying. Notice that "bae" and "bay" are pronounced exactly the same, though "ear" and "year" are not.

Comment: @bjb568 I would add "mayor" to your list in British English.  The Oxford UK English dictionary gives identical pronunciation for "mayor" and "mare".  The US English dictionary has a different pronunciation of mayor, but that doesn't have a consonant y sound either.

Comment: @bjb568: In British English bae and bay have very different pronunciations.

Comment: @bjb568: _employing_ and _enjoying_ certainly include the "y" consonant sound. I can't imagine how you could pronounce them otherwise.

Comment: @Chenmunka what do you see as the difference between the pronunciation of *bae* and *bay* in British English? I am a Br. Eng. speaker and I pronounce them exactly the same: /beɪ/ . https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bae lists them as homophones.

Comment: @JamesMartin: I have only heard bae pronounced to either rhyme with bye or with burr.

Comment: @Chenmuka Really?! Are we talking about "bae" meaning babe, baby, darling, etc?

Comment: Minus 11 so far. Most definitely a record for me. But WHY? Goodness ...

Comment: @Ricky Because you have stumbled into a specialized world of linguistics, namely phonology, and are not versed in its vocabulary or its concepts. People are talking about phonemes rather than letters. And in English, the same letter may represent several different phonemes. The a/an distinction depends on phonemes rather than letters, and the phonemes represented by letters or combinations of letters change over time. I see no reason to obsess over the downvotes; they represent very little in terms of your knowledge of the English language.

Comment: @JeffMorrow: You are in error, but the whole thing is kind of comical, actually. I mean, I'm as much of a narcissist as the next person, but in this case I truly couldn't care less what folks might or might not think of the extent of my expertise. I was merely trying to help the OP.

Comment: OK I am in error. Sorry to have been a bother.

Comment: I feel that this answer is not wrong, but also not particularly useful.  It amounts to "the difference between _year_ and _ear_ is the y at the front", which (a) doesn't really go any way towards answering the original question, and (b) has already been noticed by the OP.  I think this explains the plethora of downvotes.